# Biblatex: Change color of journal title without removing DOI links

Tags: biblatex, color, doi

I want to change the colour of all journal titles (the ones with hyperlinks and those without) to a blue colour but at the same time keep the hyperlink that uses the DOI of the journal article to link to the source of the article.

The one option I have tried is:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false}
\newbibmacro{string+doi}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{#1}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{#1}}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
```

This however produces multiple errors when compiling the PDF file.

The other option I have tried is setting the colour of the journal title seperately:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{doi=false}
\newbibmacro{string+doi}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{#1}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article]
  {journaltitle}{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{#1}}
```

Compiling this works flawlessly and the colour of the journal titles is blue, but for some reason it removes the DOI link.

Where have I gone wrong and what do I have to change to get a working output file?

Comment: @kcabdeef the second way don't work because you redefine the format and the first format is deleted. Define the format in this way: 

`\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibemph{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{#1}}}}`

and it will work.

Comment: @kcabdeef Post a MWE.

Comment: @Carlos Lanziano
your initial solution works perfectly now, I just got two ?s into the code when copying it to latex...

Comment: @CarlosLanziano Want to turn that comment of yours into an answer?

Comment: @CarlosLanziano Also asking you to asnwer the question :-) Don't forget to ping me so i can upvote.

Answer (score 2):

@kcabdeef the second way don't work because you redefine the format and the first format is deleted. Define the format in this way:

`\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\usebibmacro{string+doi}{\mkbibemph{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{#1}}}}`

and it will work.